SQL 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'
Looking for a bit of help.
I am receiving the below error when trying to count the results of a case statement involving a sum.
I am trying to find some workaround as I know this is not the correct way to do it but I am totally stumped.
In English I want to:
Count the amount of orders that has a total item quantity of 1.
The SQL I am using is:
,COUNT(CASE
WHEN SUM(delivery_line_item.dli_qty) = 1 THEN
1
ELSE
0
END)
AS SingleLineOrders
Without the Count statement, the query returns the result of 1, where I need to count all instances where the sum of dli_qty = 1.
Hopefully someone can help :)
Thanks

Your code snippet, taken verbatim, implies that you need to do two levels of aggregation, i.e. a query with two GROUP BY clauses.  To get help with your question, you should add sample input data, then show us the output you expect based on that input.

Can't nest aggregates (COUNT, SUM) without using subqueries.

Assuming your delivery_line_item table has an order_id column, you would do something like:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SingleLineOrders
FROM (
    SELECT order_id
    FROM delivery_line_item
    GROUP BY order_id
    HAVING SUM(dli_qty) = 1
) t;

The derived table returns all order_ids for which the sum of the dli_qty is one, and then the outer query counts the order_ids.
